# Php response of different function

Tags: php

```
<?php
        class abc
        {
         public function test()
         {
          echo 'hello';
          $this->test1();

         }
         public function test1()
         {
           for($i=0;$i<10000000;$i++)

            {

             echo $i;

            }
         }
        }
    ?>
```

I want when we call test then output should 
hello at once and test1 should be call on background
so that we get response hello at once and  avoid 
waiting of execution of both the function.

Comment: Turn off the buffering and it should work.

Comment: Are you wanting the 'hello' to go to the browser and then the results of test1() to just stay on the server? or do you want both results to go to the browser?

Comment: @achendrick I want hello go to the browser at once before waiting of  results of test1().

Comment: @NullPoiиteя how can we get response hello at once

Comment: @NullPoiиteя yes you can.

Comment: @Prince take a look at flush() http://us3.php.net/flush just put flush() right after your echo 'hello';

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `flush();`

After you've done your echo with `hello` in it, use `flush();` which will push the current output to the browser before the script has finished executing.

In your case:

```
public function test() {
    echo 'hello';
    flush();
    $this->test1();
}
```